# Android: reading accelerometer without memory allocation?

Tags: android, performance, memory, accelerometer

I am developing a game for Android (2.1+), using the accelerometer as user input. I use a sensor listener that I register at the beginning of the activity with the sensor manager, as follows:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(SystemRegistry.inputSystem.mSensorListener,
                                accSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

That works well and I just read the accelerometer values in `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` in order to use it in my game loop:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
     accX = event.values[0];
     accY = event.values[1];
     accY = event.values[2];
 }
```

I am writing a real-time game so I am trying to avoid any memory allocation in my code, since I want to minimize the garbage collection. The problem is that every time there is a `SensorEvent`, the sensor manager actually allocates memory. Here is for example the output of the ddms allocation tracker:

```
51  28  android.hardware.SensorEvent    9   android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate createSensorEvent   
50  28  float[] 9   android.hardware.SensorEvent    <init>
```

which shows 28*2=56 bytes allocated at every event. This seems to have the effect of triggering the garbage collector quite often, which induces some lags... So here is my question: is there a way to achieve the same thing (getting the current acceleration vector), without allocating any memory? Is there a way to actually read on demand the values of this vector without waiting for an event?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like something we need to fix on our side, I'll file a bug internally.

Comment: Oh alright, in this case I will give you more information: here is the exact location where the memory allocation happens: `createSensorEvent SensorManager.java:462`
I am using SDK v7 (Android 2.1).

Comment: 9 years later this still seems to be a problem.. or is again? Was anything done about it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem only occurs when there is more than one Sensor registered to a SensorEventListener. I think a workaround would be to use a different SensorEventListener per Sensor.

Also make sure to NOT register the SAME Sensor with two different SensorEventListener -- there  was a bug in that case that got fixed in Gingerbread.

Another, less attractive, option would be to use the Gingerbread NDK, which doesn't have this issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made sure to allow the sensor to be registered only once with the event listener, and I only use one sensor, but the leak still happens... Weird!